# NSArray mutableCopy creates new array but still points to old contents

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, deep-copy

I have an `NSMutableArray` called `playersArray` in my singleton class which holds for my applications main datasource.
Each object of `playersArray` is a `NSDictionary` and the content is like :

```
{
    sgfID = 1;
    sgfPlayer = "<PlayerContact: 0xbf851b0>";
}
```

`PlayerContact` is a `NSObject` subclass containing properties like:
NSString * playerName, playerTeam, BOOL PlayerSelected and so on.

In one of my ViewControllers, in `viewDidLoad`, I want to take a deep copy of `playersArray` in to a `NSMutableArray` named `duplicatePlayersArray`. I do this by

```
playersArray = [[SGFHelper sharedHelpers] SGFContactsArray];
duplicatePlayersArray = [playersArray mutableCopy];
```

Now that I have two separate copies, I was under the impression that playersArray and duplicatePlayersArray are two totally different arrays in the memory. However I found that they are NOT!

Even if the debugger shows that they have different memory addresses, their contents have same memory addresses. So when i do this:

```
[((NSMutableDictionary *)[duplicatePlayersArray objectAtIndex:0]) setObject:@"333" forKey:@"sgfID"];
```

playersArray's dictionary at index:0 has ALSO "333" as key "sgfID" instead of "1" as it used to before the above line of code ran.

BUT, if I run the below code, only then, the two arrays start to differ

```
[duplicatePlayersArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:tempDict];
```

Still this doesn't address my concern because the two arrays which I wanted to believe are different are still "connected". A change in one, results in the other array to change its contents.

Can you friends please show me a way to DEEP COPY the array I explained the contents of in a way where all of their contents are kept in different objects.

Comment: it is not a deep copy, but only a copy of the original array with the content dictionaries still the same

Comment: Was there *anything* in the documentation that would lead you to believe it was a deep copy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `initWithArray:copyItems:` to copy each entry in the array

```
NSMutableArray *duplicatePlayersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:playersArray copyItems:YES];
```

Comment: I am giving this a shot, will let you know asap

Comment: As you said duplicatePlayersArray now has different contents, thanks. But now, I can not update the contents of it. Xcode says NSDictionary doesn't support setObject:ForKey:. However when I run my code for playersArray I get no error. Somehow things in playersArray have become immutable. Is there a way I can duplicate playersArray the way result is mutable? or just convert duplicatePlayersArray somehow?

Comment: Best to create a new question with the exact code you're using in it.